# How to compile c program with HDF5 source code?

Tags: c++, c, hdf5, scientific-computing

I have the specific requirement where I want to compile and execute some code which has HDF5 dependencies. 
I don't want to use the `hdf5 compiler`, but I want to compile the HDF5 Source code.

I am very new on how to link the HDF5 to my C program. Please can you explain in detail how to do so, such that I can execute this program using c compiler and linking the source files which is downloaded from [here](https://support.hdfgroup.org/downloads/index.html).

Sample C program -

```
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * Copyright by The HDF Group.                                               *
 * Copyright by the Board of Trustees of the University of Illinois.         *
 * All rights reserved.                                                      *
 *                                                                           *
 * This file is part of HDF5.  The full HDF5 copyright notice, including     *
 * terms governing use, modification, and redistribution, is contained in    *
 * the files COPYING and Copyright.html.  COPYING can be found at the root   *
 * of the source code distribution tree; Copyright.html can be found at the  *
 * root level of an installed copy of the electronic HDF5 document set and   *
 * is linked from the top-level documents page.  It can also be found at     *
 * http://hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/Copyright.html.  If you do not have          *
 * access to either file, you may request a copy from help@hdfgroup.org.     *
 * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */

/*
 *  This example illustrates how to create a dataset that is a 4 x 6 
 *  array.  It is used in the HDF5 Tutorial.
 */

#include "hdf5.h"
#define FILE "dset.h5"

int main() {

   hid_t       file_id, dataset_id, dataspace_id;  /* identifiers */
   hsize_t     dims[2];
   herr_t      status;

   /* Create a new file using default properties. */
   file_id = H5Fcreate(FILE, H5F_ACC_TRUNC, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);

   /* Create the data space for the dataset. */
   dims[0] = 4; 
   dims[1] = 6; 
   dataspace_id = H5Screate_simple(2, dims, NULL);

   /* Create the dataset. */
   dataset_id = H5Dcreate2(file_id, "/dset", H5T_STD_I32BE, dataspace_id, 
                          H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);

   /* End access to the dataset and release resources used by it. */
   status = H5Dclose(dataset_id);

   /* Terminate access to the data space. */ 
   status = H5Sclose(dataspace_id);

   /* Close the file. */
   status = H5Fclose(file_id);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For compiling, it is necessary to have the `-I` flag point to the include directory of HDF5. For a system install, it will typically be `/usr/include` but there are many variations depending on whether HDF5 is installed in serial or parallel, 32/64-bit, etc. For linking the `-L` and `-l` flags are the ones that matter. `-L` should point to the directory holding the `.so`,`.dll` or `.dylib` files of the HDF5 libraries (again, there can be variations) and `-l` simply gives the library names, `-lhdf5` and others (I believe that `-lz` and `-lm` are almost always used). If you use the high-level library, `-lhdf5_hl` is needed.

The simplest way to check those flags is to call

```
h5cc -show
```

that will list them all.

PS: you can compile and link in a single step (from `.c` to executable file) or first compile (`.c` to `.o`) then link (`.o` to executable file). In the first case all `-I`, `-L` and `-l` flags are needed.